# Why are the constructor and desctructor of class A called once when creating a vector<A>?

Tags: c++, stl

In program present at end I got output like this.

```
   constructor is called
   destructor is called
   destructor is called
   destructor is called
   destructor is called
   destructor is called
   destructor is called
```

I am able to figure out that last five line **destructor is called** if because of five calls to destructor. But I am not able of understand first two lines. Why constructor is called only single time and followed by call to destructor in next line.

Please explain this. Thanks

```
class A {
    public :
    string name;
    int age;
    A(){    cout << "constructor is called" << endl;  }
    ~A() {   cout << "destructor is called"<< endl;   }
};

int main()
{
    vector<class A> vec(5);
    cout << vec.size() << endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: This is indeed a good question - but you should adjust the title so it matches the question more (something like "Why are the constructor and desctructor of class A called once when creating a vector<A>?")

Comment: I just ran your code and it prints out both constructor and destructor five times. Do you mind changing vector<class A> to vector<A> and try again?

Comment: Interesting. [Ideone.com and my Mac get completely different results](http://ideone.com/hZ0ZNx#sthash.bssoTY4Q.dpuf).

Comment: @WhozCraig Try Ideone with C++ 4.8.1

Comment: @DiegoGiagio I did that, still the output is same for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only one object is constructed by your default constructor, it is then copied 5 times. Add:

```
 A(const A&) { cout << "copy-constructor is called" << endl; }
```

to see when/where the other objects are created by copying the initial object.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta Note that the behavior is [different](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/900278368c18bfad) for C++11, where 5 different constructions take place, rather than copying the original. This is because the [constructor in question](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) was replaced by 2 constructors in C++11.

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to:

```
class A {
public :
  string name;
  int age;
  A(){    cout << "constructor is called" << endl;  }
  ~A() {   cout << "destructor is called"<< endl;   }
  A(const A&) { cout << "copy c'tor is called"<<endl;}
};
```

then you will get

```
constructor is called
copy c'tor is called
copy c'tor is called
copy c'tor is called
copy c'tor is called
copy c'tor is called
destructor is called
5
destructor is called
destructor is called
destructor is called
destructor is called
destructor is called
```

As you can see, your object is created once, but copied 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

The vector works like this:

The thing you put into vector is a copy of the thing.
The thing you get from a vector is a copy of the thing in vector.

The constructor works as( Assume your class is A):

```
A array[n];        // This one will call default constructor n times
vector<A> vec(n);  // This one will call default constructor once and copy constructor n times.
```

The essential one with default constructor create an object and this one is not put into vector

You get one original one, and 5 copies, that's why there is 6 times desctructor called

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that the behavior of that code depends on what version of the standard your compiler and library is implemnting. The behavior you describe is that of a C++03 implementation, where the constructor of vector you are using is:

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const T& value = T(),
                    const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

You are not providing the value or the allocator, so they are defaulted. If instead you explicitly create the objects you will understand what is going on:

```
vector<A> vec(5,A());     // A() is a temporary, destroyed at the end of the 
                          // whole expression.
```

That is, a temporary is created with the default constructor, producing the trace for the constructor call and is used to copy into the 5 locations. Then it is destroyed at the end of the expression. When the vector goes out of scope the 5 elements stored inside are destroyed themselves.

In C++11 the library changed, and now the signature above is split into these two signatures:

```
explicit vector(size_type n);
vector(size_type n, const T& value, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

With a C++11 implementation you would be calling the first version of the two. In this case there is no argument to the constructor, so no temporary is created. Instead the new standard requires that the implementation *default constructs* the elements in place. The output of the program would thus be 5 lines representing the default constructors when the vector is created, and 5 lines with the output from the destructors when the vector goes out of scope.